# Swift - unwrapping a Double value with a Guard let statement

Tags: swift, xcode, guard, statements

to unwrap a Double from my default values, I seem to have to do it with two `guard let` statements to unwrap the value safely such as in what follows:

```
guard let distanceAwayPreference = self.defaults.string(forKey: "distancePreference") else {
    return
}
guard let doubleDAP = Double(distanceAwayPreference) else {
    return
}
```

– because if I do it like this:

```
guard let DistanceAwayPreference = self.defaults.double(forKey: "distancePreference") else {
    return
}
```

– I get the error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Double'

Is there a better way so i can do it once, or have less code throughout my app?

Comment: you can use UserDefaults `object(forKey:)` it will return `Any?` instead of zero, therefore you can check if the value exists. ``guard let distance = self.defaults.object(forKey: "distancePreference") as? Double else {
      return
 }``

Answer (score 2):

The method `double(forKey:)` is not returning an `optional` at all. According to the documentation it returns:

> The double value associated with the specified key. If the key doesn‘t exist, this method returns 0.

So you can't optional bind it to a variable. This is why you've got that error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Double'

---

For less and cleaner code (when using it), you can use a simple property wrapper like:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: T

    init(_ key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get { UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue }
        set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key) }
    }
}
```

Then you can have a custom helper struct like this:

```
struct UserDefaultsConfig {
    @UserDefault("distancePreference", defaultValue: 0)
    static var distancePreference: Double
}
```

And use it late like:

```
UserDefaultsConfig.distancePreference = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to return Any from defaults instead of String. So, this way you can use optional casting.

```
guard let doubleDAP = self.defaults.object(forKey: "distancePreference") as? Double else {
      return
}
```